# Valor de variable no actualiza hasta cambiar de vista o hacer un hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy haciendo una carro de compras pero al intentar leer el subtotal de todos los productos me muestra como subtotal 0. Lo que estoy intnetando hacer es actuarlizar el valor de la variable y usarla en un Text widget pero solamente me muestra 0 y si cambio de vista y regreso o hago un hot reload me muestra el valor que ocupo pero en la consola me muestra el doble de ese mismo valor por ejemplo me muestra 10 en el widget pero en la consola 20.
Este es el codigo:

```
double subTotalCart = 0.00;
 Future<List<Product>> fetchCartData() async {
  List<Product> product = await readProductCart();
  return product;
}

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  Cart({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState();
}
class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchCartData();
    subTotalCart = subTotalCart;
  }
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Carro de compras'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: cartListView()  
                ) ,),),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Subtotal: $subTotalCart',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 19
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: (){},
                    child: TextData(data:'Pagar', fontSize: 19,),
                  )
                  )
                ],),)],),),); }}

class CartList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Product> products;
  CartList({Key key, this.products}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: products.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final product = products[index];
        int subtotalProducto = product.cantidad * product.precio;
        subTotalCart += subtotalProducto; 
        return Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextData(data: 'Subtotal:'),
                        TextData(data: subtotalProducto.toString())
                      ],),],),),],),);},);}}
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es que se muestre el valor de tu `subTotalCart`?

Comment: si quiero que muestre es valor en todo momento que este en esa vista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno como ya tienes un `StatefulWidget` es solo cuestión de que utilices el método `setState` para que se re dibuje tu `Text`, para eso solo hay que esperar a que tu método `readProductCart` que esta dentro de `fetchCartData` retorne la lista de productos, ahí mismo haces el calculo ejemplo:

```
for (var p in product) {
    subTotalCart += p.cantidad * p.precio;
}
```

No hay necesidad de tener los métodos fuera de la clase `_CartState` al igual que la variable `subTotalCart` por lo que la clase en general puede quedar de la siguiente manera.

```
class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  double subTotalCart = 0.00;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchCartData();
    subTotalCart = subTotalCart;
  }

  Future<List<Product>> fetchCartData() async {
    List<Product> product = await readProductCart();
    for (var p in product) {
      subTotalCart += p.cantidad * p.precio;
    }
    setState(() {});
    return product;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Carro de compras'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(child: cartListView()),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Subtotal: $subTotalCart',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: TextData(
                      data: 'Pagar',
                      fontSize: 19,
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda